# Pybind11 python bindings for Node

Tags: node, rclcpp, rclpy

I'm currently creating python bindings for [libhri](https://github.com/ros4hri/libhri/tree/humble-devel), a ROS C++ library on Humble. The current C++ implementation (not public yet) takes a rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr argument to internally create topic subscriptions and logs. The problem is now providing this node pointer from an rclpy.Node object.

Even though rclpy uses pybind11 bindings, they wrap around [rcl](https://github.com/ros2/rclpy/blob/humble/rclpy/src/rclpy/node.cpp#L379), not rclcpp, so direct casting from rclpy.Node to rclcpp::Node seems not doable. I could get the [rcl_node_t handle from rclpy](https://github.com/ros2/rclpy/blob/humble/rclpy/rclpy/node.py#L307), but I'm not sure if I could use it to recover an rclcpp:Node from it.

Is this approach feasible, and if yes, how?
If not, are there any best practices on how to create python bindings of ROS libraries (e.g., always create standalone nodes/executors in libraries, or at the opposite spectrum pass external node callbacks for every required Node method required by the library).